# How to use 3rd party framework depends from dylib for IOS in Delphi Firemonkey

Tags: ios, delphi, frameworks, firemonkey, dylib

I'm using 3rd-party SDK, presented as libXXX.a, that needs

- libstdc++.dylib
- libz.dylib

15/05/2017 ANSWER.
Finally I have found a time to write down my solution.
If your 3rd party SDK depends from some dynamic libraries, do this:

1. For example dynamic library is called as "libSuperLibrary.dylib".
2. For example 3rd party SDK is called as "SuperFramework.framework".
3. Go to "Project - Options - Delphi Compilier - Framework Search Path"
4. Fill the field by path to your framework like "C:\path\to\my\frameworks\"
5. Go to "Project - Options - Linking - Options passed to the LD linked"
6. Fill the field by string "-ObjC -framework SuperFramework -lSuperLibrary
7. Compile

Comment: What is 'Embarcadero's "brilliant" way of using static libraries'? If you're going to criticise them, please explain why, otherwise it just sounds snarky. Better to keep the question a neutral question and if you think something was done badly, explain so (at least with a link.)

Comment: Do you have to do that for each method in the class? If so, that does seem odd. Have you entered a QP to make a better system? (http://quality.embarcadero.com. Please post a link here and I'll vote for it. Please include a quick sample of both what the current system is and what it should be - remember it's a bug report and the more you can help out whoever triages the reports, to make them realise it's important, the better.)

Answer (score 0):

IOS does not allow dynamic libraries. When building with XCode it automatically links the needed static libraries, but only in the final app, not if you build a static library. Instead you can tell Delphi to handle the dependencies.

In the pascal header file for libXXX.a (where you import the functions to Delphi) add `dependency` like this:

```
function  MyFunction; cdecl; external libXXX.a name 'myfunction' dependency 'stdc++'
```

I have used it my self with 'c++' (which corresponds to 'libc++.dylib') and 'stdc++' (corresponds to 'libstdc++.dylib'), but you will have to try your self if it works with the z library.

Read more here:
http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Seattle/en/Procedures_and_Functions#Specifying_Dependencies_of_the_Library

Comment: I edited my post. What do you think I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Write 'stdc++' instead of 'libstdc++.dylib'.

Comment: Update your question with the new errors, because they must be different than before.

Comment: I don't know what else is going wrong in your situation, but using `dependency`is the solution to at least one of the problems you had.

Comment: I think the same, but when IDE throw "library not found for -llibz.dylib" it means that somewhere I missed the directory that must contains such library OR I made wrong format usage of library in code. So what is that misterious folder OR format usage?