# How to add 3rd-Party Framework to Delphi iOS Project?

Tags: ios, delphi, frameworks, firemonkey

I need to use Wacom Bluetooth Stylus SDK to a FireMonkey Project (iOS) in Delphi 10.4. This framework includes the framework (obvious) and a '.bundle' resources. How do I add these framework to the project in order to use its classes and methods?
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You need to run the framework through a transform tool which will generate the pascal header files for you and give you access to the classes you need.

https://community.idera.com/developer-tools/b/blog/posts/quickly-auto-generate-ios-osx-and-android-headers-for-delphi-and-c-builder

This tool is the best available for iOS but requires a bit of setup in terms of where to put your framework file (it needs to be in the same folder as the iOS SDK files Delphi uses) and the location of clang etc. The above article is helpful for this.

After being generated you then need to link in your .a framework file which is usually the file in the framework bundle with the same name as the framework but no extension. Just rename with a .a extension.
Linking in can be done two ways - statically by adding into the linker options field under the compiler section of your profile (you may need a -objc parameter too) or you can lazy reference it in your code so the compiler automatically pulls it in.

This SO reference explains the fake loader concept:

[How to use 3rd party framework depends from dylib for IOS in Delphi Firemonkey](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33549619/how-to-use-3rd-party-framework-depends-from-dylib-for-ios-in-delphi-firemonkey)

It can be a little bit of a black art to get it working as the error messages are vague if it goes wrong but hopefully the above helps.